# MongoDB Compass doesn't connect with Atlas connection string. | Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND

Tags: node.js, mongodb, connection-string, mongodb-atlas, mongodb-compass

When I try to connect using the connection string copied from the MongoDB Atlas cluster, and paste it into Compass a warning message appears, and connect button is disabled.

```
Connection string is:
mongodb+srv://nelson:nelson@cluster1.f7a6f.mongodb.net/test

Warning: 
querySrv ENODATA _mongodb._tcp.cluster1.f7a6f.mongodb.net
```

> If I remove the **+srv** from the connection string then the warning disappears but the connection still not being successful.

```
Connection error:
"getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND cluster1.f7a6f.mongodb.net"
```

Please guide me on what am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: What version of compass are you using?

Comment: Are you able to connect from `mongo` shell?

Comment: No, mongo shell also not connecting. Local database connection successfully connected within shell and compass both but Atlas connection returns error.

Comment: Version 1.25.0 (1.25.0)